# How to set-up Transactional Replication in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

In the November 2015 blog post [Transactional Replication to Azure SQL DB now in public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/) we're told that we "can now configure Azure SQL DB as a subscriber of SQL Server Transactional Replication". The instructions for how to do so are in other posts, and involve these settings (available through SSMS):

[image: SSMS Screenshot from Timothy Khouri's blog]

Wind forward to January 2017. When I look at my Azure SQL database in SSMS there is no "Replication", just "Databases" and "Security". How do I access the replication setup for Azure SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement page says..

> This new capacity of Transactional Replication is available starting with the following versions\updates of SQL Server:
>
> Community Technology Preview (CTP) 3.0 of SQL Server 2016
> SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 Cumulative Update 3
> SQL Server 2014 RTM Cumulative Update 10
> SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2 Cumulative Update 8

Do you meet this requirements  ?

further this is one way replication, which means  your onpremises will act as both publisher and distributor ..Azure acts as subscriber

> You will see the replication to azure option in onpremise databases,which satisfy above said requirements

Comment: Thanks - so to do it in Azure solely I'll need to roll my own. Note that the option should still be there off-premises in Azure to subscribe, even if publish is greyed out or missing?

Comment: i am sorry,i didn't understand your current comment..You can  go to onpremises database and in replication tab,you will have an option to choose azure database..